# Why does the return trip of the IC Bus Antwerp-Eindhoven take almost 3 hours, whereas the outbound takes 1.15h?

Tags: buses, eindhoven, antwerp

The [IC bus](http://www.bahn.com/i/view/BEL/nl/prices/europe/ic-bus.shtml) from Antwerp to Eindhoven takes 1h15m hours. However the return takes 2h50m hours. Why is this?

Comment: Must be the time zone difference. :)

Comment: I guess travel.se isn't what it was before :( Sorry for the disturbance, continue playing

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a typo. On the detailed [schedule](http://www.bahn.com/i/view/mdb/bahnintern/angebotsberatung/ic_bus/fahrplaene2014/duesseldorf_-_antwerpen/november_2014/mdb_173903_flyer_ic_bus_dea_dt.pdf). Both the outbound and return trip seem to be in par.